# Is it possible use a custom 'select' template for bunlded products in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I'm creating a specific bundled product, which needs a few custom changes to the select and checkbox templates.

Supposedly I could just add a custom update layout in the product, but nothing I do seems to be able to target a new select.phtml template.

```
<reference name="product.info.options.wrapper">
 <!-- THIS WORKS -->
 <block type="bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle" name="product.info.bundle.options" as="type_bundle_options" template="bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/*custom*.phtml">
  <action method="addRenderer">
    <type>select</type>
    <block>bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_select</block>  
    <!-- THIS DOESN'T WORK -->
    <template>*custom_folder*/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/*custom*-select.phtml</template>
  </action>
 </block>
 <action method="insert"><block>product.info.bundle.options</block></action>
</reference>
```

Looking at the catalog.xml, it looks like the checkboxes, and selects, etc ... point to a template, but not in bundle.xml.

And, I can of course overwrite the default templates in *theme*/template/bundle/catalog/...etc../option/select.phtml ... but I really need a specific template for one product ... not all of them.

I'm hoping somebody has some insight into this? Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

> etc/config.xml

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <core_layout_block_create_after>
            <observers>
                <change_bundle_select_template>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>company_module/observer</class>
                    <method>bundleChangeTemplate</method>
                </change_bundle_select_template>
            </observers>
        </core_layout_block_create_after>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

> Model/Observer.php

```
public function bundleChangeTemplate($observer)
{
    if ($observer->getBlock() instanceof Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option_Select) {
        $observer->getBlock()->setTemplate('bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/sel.phtml');
    }
}
```